# What action can I take within an onBeforeRequest listener?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I know that in an onBeforeRequest blocking listener I can cancel or redirect. Can I do anything else? What I would like to do is redirect, and then manipulate the DOM of the resultant redirected page.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) cover all the scenarios that you can use onBeforeRequest for.

If you want to redirect and then manipulate the DOM take a look at [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) or [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). Using content scripts you can specify the URL the content script is injected into.